# Android Spinner OnItemSelectedListener not working accurately

Tags: android, spinner

I have created a Spinner and activated the listener:

```
customerListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        // I do some work here
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        isInitRadioGroup = false;
    }
 );
```

I have added three values in the Spinner initially: "Search", "Employee", "Company".
If the user selects "Search", a new ListActivity is shown and the selected value is added to the above Spinner as a result.
Like this, I am performing some action on the selection of the spinner Item. Now, When the screen is shown at first time, by default "Search" is shown. To trigger the processing of the ListActivity, the user has to select the "Search" again. This time, on ItemSelected callback is not called. I mean to say, if a value in Spinner is already selected, then on the selection of the same value again, does not trigger the listener.

Whereas:
When the screen is shown at first time, by default "Search" is shown. The user selects the value "Employee" (processing for this is done, onItemSelected is called as the previous selected value is different than the value selected by the user). The user then selects the value "Search". This time the onItemSelected method is called and successfully adds a new value to the Spinner.

This is a bug of Android. I have checked there is no error in my code.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the spinner as following

```
Spinner genspin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gender);

ArrayAdapter<String> genadap=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.spinneritems,String_array);
genadap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
genspin.setAdapter(genadap);
genspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

then you can get the selected value as

```
genspin.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Comment: Surendra, there is no issue in getting the Selected value of the spinner. What I want is when the client changes the value of the spinner (or re- selects the same value) then some action needs to be performed. For this, when the user selects different value than what was selected, onItemSelected is called, but when the user re-selects the same value (like "Search"), onItemSelected is not called. I cannot manually force the callback to fire.